# How can I find out the version of given / installed Boost headers?

Tags: c++, boost

Looking at a folder containing Boost headers I would like to find out which version of Boost that is.

Libraries have such information embedded inside or in their name. That's great.
But I wonder how to find that out with a header only-folder of Boost?
Which Boost documentation should I resort to, when using it?

I could, as a last resort, look at the date of creation of the files on the filesystem and guess that they cannot be part of any later Boost releases. Pfft. Someone can help?

(No, I would not have the option to "just replace that and update it to most recent / know version".)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkout `version.hpp` in the root `include/` folder:

```
#define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_50_0"
```

This is the version number, with the dots replaced by underscores (here 1.50.0).

If you want to check compatibility automatically inside your header files, there is a numerical field, too:

```
//  BOOST_VERSION % 100 is the sub-minor version
//  BOOST_VERSION / 100 % 1000 is the minor version
//  BOOST_VERSION / 100000 is the major version

#define BOOST_VERSION 105000
```

Comment: Ahh! So obvious! I was looking for some kinda history/readme.txt or so...  now that is telling me to tune my search terms, too. (I did not get any helping search results) thx